# Error when attempting to open Control Panel

Tags: windows-10, control-panel, run-dialog

I used to open Windows 10 control panel by issuing 'control' command in run window. Recently this fails, leaving the following message:

`There was a problem sending the command to the program. ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0`

[image: Error]

What would the reason and the solution be?

Comment: If you right-click the Start button and click "Control Panel" does it give you the same error?  Have you run a `sfc /scannow` yet?

Comment: Yes. but is says:
```sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.```

Comment: After working on this problem I finally found the reason not the way out: it is due to "Directory Opus windows explorer replacement feature". On Windows 10 it does NOT work properly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had replaced Windows Explorer as default directory browser with Q-Dir. This was resolved with a Registry script from the maker of Q-Dir: https://www.softwareok.com/?page=Windows/Info/Q-Dir/8